# Update a collection of the parent class in the current object's class

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say I have 2 classes:

```
class Folder
{
    public  List<File> AssociatedFiles { get; set; }
}

class File
{
    void Update()
    {
        //How to update parent class and add items to the list
        // Something like AssociatedFiles.Add(...); which obviously I can't
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I wanted to call:

```
myFolder.AssociatedFiles.Update();
```

And update the AssociatedFiles of `myFolder` which is an instance of the `Folder` class.

That may be basics of OOP, but I'm trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: this.add() isnt it?

Comment: did you meant -`class File : Folder{}` ??

Comment: You will have to either select 1 or more of those items. The simplest way is to use a foreach loop and iterate them.

Comment: @Green No. I don't want my `File` class to extend the `Folder` class.  A folder contains a collections of files and I want to update that collection from within the `File` class.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny That would be if I were to update it in the `Folder` class.

Comment: Wow...somehow I missed it. got you

Comment: Do you want to access the `AssociatedFiles` collection from the `Update` method on the `File`?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes.

Comment: `Update()` can be `Update(Folder myParentFolder)` and you could call it like `Foreach(File f in folder.AssociatedFiles){ f.Update(folder); }`

Comment: If people that downvoted had tell me what was the problem it would be so much easier for me to change my question accordingly. Always a shame...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to add a backreference to a folder inside the File class.

```
class Folder

{
    public  List<File> AssociatedFiles { get; set; }
}

class File
{
    public Folder ParentFolder {get; set;}
    //create a constructor that takes the folder as a parameter
    public class File(Folder myFolder) {this.ParentFolder = myFolder;}
    void Update()
    {
        this.ParentFolder.AssociatedFiles.Add()
    }
}
```

Now, when you initialize a File, instead of calling File() you would call File(folder) and pass it the folder.